# Does the theory of theta functions ever go beyond just random caulculations and ugly formulas?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

I recently took a class in elliptic functions and found the theory of elliptic functions very clean. You get very powerful results and the proofs are usually short and intuitive. Then we learned about modular forms where the proofs became less clean but were still fine and still yielded nice results. But when we finally covered theta functions/jacobi forms, the proofs boiled down to nothing more than "plug it in and simplify the gigantic, ugly, random terms". This went on for multiple lectures and happened in every lecture that touched on theta functions. Is this really all there is to this theory? Just simplifying ugly algebraic expressions to obtain more ugly algebraic expressions?

We were told that theta functions are a hybrid between elliptic functions and modular forms. I thus expexted their theory to be a mix of both theories. But instead, it resembles neither.

Comment: Can you link to your lecture notes or anything similar? Experts here might conclude they happen to take an unnecessarily ugly approach to the relevant proofs.

Comment: Out of privacy reasons, I would prefer not to, but theyre not in english anyways. But when I check wikipedia or books on the topic like the one from freitag/busam, I dont see *any* clean formulas. Its all just a mess of huge exponential functions and random constants. I can deal with that fact if it eventually stops, but I keep scrolling and scrolling and scrolling and cant find *any* concise formula. And without those, I dont know how you can skip the "plug it in and simplify the mess"-approach